# Функция сравнения 2-х списков в Haskell

Tags: список, сравнение, haskell

Работа заставила изучать Haskell. Столкнулся с необходимостью написания функции, на вход которой подаются два списка. Она сравнивает их, если все элементы совпадают, то True, если нет( также либо элемент лишний, либо не хватает элемента), то False. Элементы должны быть в одинаковом порядке. Сижу думаю как это сделать. На мысль прихдит функция elem. но как ее приписать не знаю

Answer (score 5):

Для списков определена операция сравнения `(==)` - при условии, что она определена для элемента списка. Поэтому списки можно просто-напросто сравнить:

```
[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]   -- True
[1,2,3] == [1,2,4]   -- False
[1,2,3] == [1,3]     -- False
```

---

Если же это "домашняя работа" - и следовательно, пользоваться встроенными операциями запрещено, - то "правильный" (в смысле образования) ответ - это реализовать функцию "с нуля".

Для этого ход мысли должен быть такой: если оба списка не пустые, и первые элементы их равны друг другу, то равенство списков тождественно равенству их "хвостов". Давайте это запишем:

```
compare (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x == y) = compare xs ys
```

Далее, если первые элементы не равны друг другу, то списки сразу не равны. Запишем:

```
compare (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x /= y) = False
```

Эти два случая можно описать чуть по-другому: списки равны если их первые элементы равны *И* их "хвосты" тоже равны. Запишем это:

```
compare (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x == y) && (compare xs ys)
```

Идём дальше. Какие ещё могуть быть случаи? Первый список может быть пустым. В этом случае списки равны тогда и только тогда, когда второй список тоже пустой:

```
compare [] [] = True
```

В любых других случаях (а именно - первый пустой/второй не пустой или наоборот) списки не равны:

```
compare _ _ = False
```

И теперь сведём все случаи вместе:

```
compare (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x == y) && (compare xs ys)
compare [] [] = True
compare _ _ = False
```

Вот и всё!

Answer (score 0):

Можно склеить два списка с помощью `zip`, а затем проверить на равенство получившиеся пары с помощью `all`:

`all (\(x,y) -> x == y) $ zip [1,2,3] [1,2,3]`

Это сработает, если списки имеют одинаковую длину. Для исключения списков с разной длиной можно добавить соответствующее условие.